# window.open(url, 'Download') is not downloading file

Tags: javascript, windows, download

I have the following codes as shown below. The codes successfully save a file in the server and it returns the url of the saved file.  Now I want to download the said file, so I used "window.open(url, 'download');"  But when a new window opens, it's not downloading the file.  I still need to hit "enter" key to have the window download dialog box pop-up.  How to fix this issue to automatically download the file without pressing "enter" key.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ExportGroupSets", "Home")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ .... Parameters ....
    }),
    success: function(url) {
        if (url == "Error: Your connection to this website has timed out. Please login again.") {
            alert(url);
            return;
        }
        window.open(url, 'Download');

        $("#window").data("kendoWindow").close();
    },
    error: (function() {
        alert("Error to retrieve selected report");
    })
});
```

Comment: Adding "Download" as window name does not doenload a file. You can give the mime type of "application/octet-stream" to trigger a download dialog which you cannot avoid

Comment: You need to change that on the server

Comment: any code snippets? Thanks